# Resize image in NSTextView to fit

Tags: macos, nstextview, nsimage, nstextattachment

I have `NSAttributedString` objects with embedded images. These are being presented in `NSTextView`s. In iOS, I was able to resize the bounds of `NSTextAttachment`, and this makes the image fit.

```
extension NSTextAttachment {
    func setImageWidth(width: CGFloat, range: NSRange) {
        var thisImage = image
        if thisImage == nil {
            thisImage = imageForBounds(bounds, textContainer: nil, characterIndex: range.location)
        }
        if thisImage != nil {
            let ratio = thisImage!.size.height / thisImage!.size.width
            bounds = CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x, bounds.origin.y, width, ratio * width)
            print("New Bounds: \(bounds)")
        }
    }
}
```

This code also runs on OSX, but it does not actually resize the image. Below you can see, there is a box of the correct size around the image, but the actual image overflows the box.

[image]

I have also followed the following guide: [Implementing Rich Text with Images on OS X and iOS](https://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/implementing-rich-text-with-images-on-os-x-and-ios/). This moves the code to subclasses, but has the same effect.

Any suggestions? Is there something besides `NSTextAttachment.bounds` that I should be adjusting?

**UPDATE**

I found that modifying the `size` component of `NSImage` works! However, it is now showing all my images upside, but at the correct size. :(

Comment: If you would like to allow users to resize images, I've created a library to do just that: https://github.com/josephessin/ResizableTextAttachment.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

```
extension NSImage {
    func resizeToFit(containerWidth: CGFloat) {
        var scaleFactor : CGFloat = 1.0
        let currentWidth = self.size.width
        let currentHeight = self.size.height
        if currentWidth > containerWidth {
            scaleFactor = (containerWidth * 0.9) / currentWidth
        }
        let newWidth = currentWidth * scaleFactor
        let newHeight = currentHeight * scaleFactor

        self.size = NSSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
        print("Size: \(size)")
    }
}
```

As I mentioned in the update, you need to change the `NSImage.size`. The flip was coming from one of the subclasses I had left in there from the link in the question. Once I went back to the main classes, it works!